# deploying rest api war and starting with App Manager produces error FAIL - Application at context path

Tags: spring, api, rest, tomcat

First time working with web apps and created a simple springboot rest api and it worked fine locally. Deployed the war to a tomcat server by copying the war file into the /webapps/ directory and restarted tomcat.
I checked if this was successful by opening the tomcat web application manager page and can see the app listed:

http://1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/manager/

When I click start to get it running the following error appears:

```
 FAIL - Application at context path [/first_restapi] could not be started
```

I searched around and most answers suggest ensuring all pom file dependencies are included and to check the logs. I checked the logs on the tomcat server and the following error stuck out:

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class 
[org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: 
Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace 
[http://www.springframework.org/schema/security]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
```

I did not include a servlet-context.xml file as the tutorial did not show that. But I added it anyway and still got the same error. Can anyone help with this issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" 
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring- 
    beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">


<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<security:http auto-config="true" create-session="stateless">
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" 
             requires-channel="http"/>
             <security:http-basic />
</security:http>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a dependency problem. For each XML namespace that you (effectively) use in your configuration file, you need the appropriate `NamespaceHandler`. So in your case, to use the:

- `beans` or `util` namespace you need [`spring-beans.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans/5.3.4),
- `context` or `task` namespace you need [`spring-context.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context/5.3.4),
- `mvc` namespace you need [`spring-webmvc.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/5.3.4),
- `security` namespace you need [`spring-security-config.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config/5.4.5).

You certainly don't have the last one dependency.